# How to fix Tooling instance could not be started, another attempt will be made - Anypoint Studio 7.3 - MacOsX

Tags: macos, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

i am new in anypoint studio. I was going through data weave quick start guides and keep facing this error.

org.mule.tooling.client.startup.ToolingNotAvailableException: Tooling instance could not be started, another attempt will be made.

i have seen some solutions but they are for windows, I am using Macos Mojave and Jdk 1.8.211.

Any Idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try solution II here:

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Anypoint-Studio-7-1-3-error-tooling-not-available-exception

Open a terminal:

`cd /Applications/AnypointStudio7.app/Contents/Eclipse/`

`vi AnypointStudio.ini`

Add

```
-Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
```

after the last line.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by doing this step.

Anupoint Studio -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Execution Environment -> Select Java SE 1.8 -> Apply & Close -> Restart Studio.